# Image to custom directory android 11+

Tags: java, android, android-11, android-12

-edit: i would love some input on what i am doing wrong here why is this not working i am currently working on a college project which has a deadline pretty soon i looked at a lot of tutorials online but nothing seems to address this topic specifically for android 11 everyone seems to be using mediastore api

-edit-2: i dont understand what i am doing wrong also i have not gotten any response yet i am not able to figure out the error this is for my college project i would be very thankful if someone helped me in finding out what is wrong why is this not getting any traction i am unsure

I want to add images to a custom directory in android 11 + i have an array of bitmaps and would like to store images in a custom directory
here are my permissions in manifest file

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
    tools:ignore="ScopedStorage" />

<!-- Without this entry storage-permission entry will not be visible under app-info permissions list Android-10 and below -->
<uses-permission
    android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
    android:maxSdkVersion="29"
    tools:ignore="ScopedStorage"/>
```

here is the java code

```
 if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.R && false == Environment.isExternalStorageManager()) {
            Uri uri = Uri.parse("package:" + BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID);
            startActivity(new Intent(Settings.ACTION_MANAGE_APP_ALL_FILES_ACCESS_PERMISSION, uri));
        }
        File direct = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/LaundryImages");
        if (!direct.exists()) {
            File wallpaperDirectory = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/LaundryImages");
            wallpaperDirectory.mkdir();
        }

        String name = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss", Locale.getDefault()).format(new Date());
        TextView tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);

        File direct2 = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/LaundryImages/"+name);
        direct2.mkdir();
        int i=0;
        for (Bitmap bm : l) {
            i++;
//            tv.setText(String.valueOf(i));
            File file = new File(direct2,String.valueOf(i)+".jpg");

            try {
                FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
                if(file == null)tv.setText("null");
                bm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, out);
                out.flush();
                out.close();

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


        }
```

i tried to run it but it does not work it is creating the directories properly but it does not add the images

i tried to add images in the folder used permissions as i found on the internet and also checked whether permissions were there in my phone but still the images wont store

Comment: You may not be allowed to distribute your app on the Play Store or elsewhere, due to your use of `MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`.

Comment: i am not concerned with that i would just like for my app to work

Comment: Only call mkdir() if the directory does not exist. And if you call mkdir() then check the return value as it might fail. If it fails then stop and display a toast to inform the user. Please adapt your code here.

Comment: the directory is being made i checked but the image is not getting stored

Comment: since i am using the time stamp to make the directory which will be unique every time hence i need not check weather the directory already exists